# simple_html_dom add class or ID to a table

Tags: css, simple-html-dom

I am trying to use simple_html_dom to open a file and replace TR attributes.

The file contains a table with several rows with no css class or id assigned:

```
<tr OnMouseOver="changeCouleur(this);" onMouseOut="remetCouleur(this);" OnClick="show('13510.php');">
```

I use this code to get only the table from the loaded page:

```
$html = file_get_html('mandats/banque.html');

foreach ($html->find('table') as $node) 
{ echo $node;}
```

So far the table shows properly, but i was not able to remove OnMouseOver and onMouseOut and to add a css class to modify the row.

I tried with :
`$html->find('table,0')->class = 'mndlnk';` with no success

Basically i want to remove all current attributes, keep the link reference and insert a css class to each tr element.

Thanks in advance for your precious suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you have

```
$html->find('table,0')->class = 'mndlnk';
```

assuming that code was pasted here correctly it looks like you accidently put the ',0' inside of the quotes it should be

```
$html->find('table',0)->class = 'mndlnk';
```

if that still doesn't work, you might also want to try

```
$html->find('table', 0)->setAttribute('class', 'mndlnk');
```